# Bounded and uniformly bounded Sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

My professor explained to us that

$f_n (x)=\frac{1}{n\,x}$, $x\in(0,1]$

is bounded but not uniformly bounded. However $f_n (x)$ is uniformly bounded for $x\in (a,1]$ and $0<a<1$

He also said that

$g_n (x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$, $x\in R$

is not bounded but is uniformly bounded for $x\in [-b,b]$

I am confused at this point because $g_{n}(x)$ is not bounded because $g_{n}(x)$ blow up as $x\rightarrow{\infty}$ but $f_{n}(x)$ also blows up as $x\rightarrow{0}$ yet its bounded.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Thanks

Comment: The $f_n$ are not a bounded sequence on $(0,1]$. They all assume arbitrary large values. What is your definition of a function sequence $f_n$ to be bounded? (and uniformly bounded)?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, a sequence of functions is bounded if $\forall{x}$, $\exists M_{x}$ such that $|f_n (x)|<M_{x}$, $\forall{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, bounded means pointwise bounded.

Then $f_n(x)$ is indeed pointwise bounded, as $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{nx} \le \frac{1}{x}$. So, using $M_x = \frac{1}{x}$, for all $n$ we have $|f_n(x)| \le M_x$.

Similarly $g_n(x)$ is also bounded, using $M_x = x + 1$, as $|g_n(x)| = |x + \frac{1}{n}| \le x+1$ for all $n$.

So in my opinion (using the definition you stated in the comment), both these sequences are bounded, not uniformly bounded, but are uniformly bounded on restricted domains $(a,1]$ and $[-b,b]$ resp.