# bounded Sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis

$F_n(x)=\left(1+ \frac xn \right)^n$

[Bounded and uniformly bounded Sequence of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613321/bounded-and-uniformly-bounded-sequence-of-functions)

I tried as someone solved in this link but I think i should not take n =1
So I took n tend to infinite
Then it became $e^x$
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (2) 
}
$$

Now can I say that function is less then or equal to $e^x$ ?
I'm just talking about boundedness not uniformly boundedness since I think it is not uniform bounded if I don't restrict x to closed interval.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $$g_n (x)=n\ln (1+\frac {x}{n})-x $$

$$g'_n (x)=\frac {n}{n+x}-1=\frac {-x}{n+x} $$

$g_n $ is decreasing at $[0,+\infty) $, then

$g_n (x)\le g_n(0 )=0$.

$$\implies n\ln(1+\frac {x}{n})\le x $$
$$\implies (1+\frac {x}{n})^n\le e^x $$

for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit complicated ..? If we just let n tend to infinity , what will be the problem?

Comment: And also that should be n, not 1/n in the power don't you think?

Comment: @Ikuyuki Yes thnx